# oAuth2 invalid request - missing client_id

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0

I am getting the error even though everything seems to be fine:

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();


const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/login`
);
```

and the .env file

```
CLIENT_ID=value
CLIENT_SECRET=value
PUBLIC_URL=http://localhost:5000
```

instead of "value" there are the keys and they are the right values as i've just got them from google api console.

The rest of the app is the code from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps , copied 1:1.

Answer (score 1):

> oAuth2 invalid request - missing client_id

Following could be the potential reasons for getting this error from the OAuth2 library.

You'd provided the wrong credentials details (`client_id` & `client_secret`). So please check that by logging those values somewhere for inspection during code execution.

If you're using authorization grant flow, you've to pass the `redirect_url` where you want to receive the intermediate code which you can later use for exchanging it with real `access_token`.
For example:

```
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
  YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET,
  YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to respond. I checked them and i still have the error...